# How to fix "libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"?

Tags: lubuntu, shared-library

I'm just starting out with Lubuntu and I've just installed DaVinci Resolve to do my video editing on.

But when I click its icon on the desktop, the loading symbol comes up and stops. When I run it in the console I get this error message:

> error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is a bit beyond me. Any help?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader/issues/95, you can use:

```
wget -q -O /tmp/libpng12.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb \
  && dpkg -i /tmp/libpng12.deb \
  && rm /tmp/libpng12.deb
```

Comment: Saved my life this one. There is a library called wkhtmltopdf and version 12.4 binary has problems with rendering images served via https. 12.5 fixes that but the repo used in the project I inherited is not maintained any more, and I had to get it from a pull request. It didn't work because of specific libpng and libjpeg versions missing. Leaving this comment here for google algorithms in case someone in the future has a similar issue.