# lbreakout2: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, dpkg, games

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10.

Trying the suggestion from [How to fix "libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978294/how-to-fix-libpng12-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-direc) I got the answer:

> dpkg: regarding /tmp/libpng12.deb containing libpng12-0:amd64:
> usrmerge conflicts with libpng12-0 (<< 1.2.54-4~)   libpng12-0:amd64
> (version 1.2.54-1ubuntu1) is to be installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/libpng12.deb (--install):
> conflicting packages - not installing libpng12-0:amd64

Is there any way to make LBreakout2 run under Ubuntu 21.10?

Comment: Also check https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/lbreakout2 , the package is in the universe repository. Installation is as simple as `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lbreakout2` .

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't really fix my problem, however it helped me to fix it.

Comment: There was still (a link I assume, I didn't look it up) `/usr/local/bin/lbreakout2` present, that resulted in the same error message, even after I removed the package (???). After I removed it, and replaced it by
`sudo ln -s /usr/games/lbreakout2 /usr/local/bin/lbreakout2`
the game is working again.